# CS0120 occurs (functions) Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
public int[,] position = new int[8, 8];

Figure pawn1 = new Figure();
void Start()
{
    pawn1.Create("pawn", 1, new Vector2Int(1, 2));
}

void Update()
{

}

[System.Serializable]
public class Figure
{
    public int id;
    public void Create(string nameEntered, int IdEntered, Vector2Int positionEntered)
    {
        position[positionEntered.x, positionEntered.y] = IdEntered;
        //CS0120 occurs here
    }
}
```

Getting this error and dont know how to fix it
Is there anyone who´s able to help? 
Any kinda help is appreciated

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Can you post full class? I see start and update are not in figure. Did you check out https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/206496883-What-is-CS0120-

Answer (score 1):

[CS0120](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0120) means

> An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'member'

---

The reference to

```c#
public int[,] position = new int[8, 8];
```

is `non-static` or `instanced` since it doesn't use the keyword `static`. That means the only way to access it is over the reference of the instance of the outer class.

---

The solution depends on what you want to do with it:

If you want it `non-static` so that it is **not** "shared" between all instances of the outer class a solution could be to pass on your outer classe's instance reference like

```c#
private void Start()
{
    pawn1.Create("pawn", 1, new Vector2Int(1, 2), this);
}
```

And in **Figure** expect according value (replace `<OuterType>` by the outer classes actual name)

```c#
[System.Serializable]
public class Figure
{
    public int id;
    public void Create(string nameEntered, int IdEntered, Vector2Int positionEntered, <OuterType> reference)
    {
        reference.position[positionEntered.x, positionEntered.y] = IdEntered;
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can make it `static` so it is "shared" between all instances of the outer class:

```c#
public static int[,] position;
```

---

**Hint1**
If that is all your `Create` method is supposed to do why not setting the value in the outer class itself?

```c#
private void Start()
{
    position[1,2] = 1;
    // Rather pass on the value in this direction if Figure needs it
    pawn1 = new Figure("pawn", position[1,2], /*...*/);
}
```

Than there is no need to pass `position` etc on to the `Figure` instance and than get the value written back (unless there is happening more you didn't show).

**Hint2**
Instead of create a new `Figure` in

```c#
Figure pawn1 = new Figure();
```

and than later use its method `Create` to setup a value you should probably rather use the constructor e.g.:

```c#
[System.Serializable]
public class Figure
{
    public int id;
    public Figure(string nameEntered, int IdEntered, Vector2Int positionEntered, <OuterType> reference)
    {
        reference.position[positionEntered.x, positionEntered.y] = IdEntered;
    }
}
```

and use it like e.g.

```c#
Figure pawn1;

private void Start()
{
    pawn1 = new Figure("pawn", 1, new Vector2Int(1, 2), this);
}
```

**Hint3**
The usage of `Start` and `Update` let's conclude that you are very probably using a `MonoBehaviour`.

To avoid confusion with the `transform.position` I'ld recommend to name your field maybe better `Positions`.

**Hint4**
So far you are not using any of the `Vector2Int`'s functionality but use it only to get the two `int` values.

In case you are not doing anything else  with `positionEntered` it would be less overhead to instead of passing on a `new Vector2Int` only to get two `int` values simply pass on the `int` values themselves

```c#
pawn1.Create("pawn", 1, 1, 2, this);
```

and

```c#
public void Create(string nameEntered, int IdEntered, int x, int y, <OuterType> reference)
{
    reference.position[x, y] = IdEntered;
}
```

**Hint5**
In general if you are using `MonoBehaviour` components but you are not using one of `Start` or `Update` etc remove them entirely from your class because Unity calls them as soon as they exist which causes unnecesary overhead.